# How to insert table from view where the view's column is IFNULL(1/0, 0)?

Tags: mysql

My environment:

MariaDB 10.3.10

I create a table pe:

```
CREATE TABLE pe (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  weight int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  height int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

id, weight, height
1, 63, 172
2, 62, 173
3, null, null
4, 60, null
```

And create a view pe_view:

```
CREATE VIEW pe_view AS
SELECT
weight, height, IFNULL(FORMAT(weight/height/height*10000, 2), 0) AS bmi
FROM pe;
```

Then create a table pe_per_year:

```
CREATE TABLE pe_per_year (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  weight int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  height int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  bmi double(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, I want to INSERT INTO pe_per_year FROM pe_view. I use:

```
INSERT INTO
pe_per_year(weight, height, bmi)
SELECT weight, height, bmi
FROM pe_view;
```

And it tells me 'division by zero'. What is my wrong please? And how to insert some IFNULL(1/0, 0) datas into double(5,2) please?

Comment: Rewriting your `bmi` formula as `if(height = 0 or height is null or weight is null, 0, ROUND(weight/height/height*10000, 2))` would probably solve your problem

Comment: Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements for the relevant tables described in your problem

Comment: @Nick Thank you, it works good now.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thank you, I put the create statements there now.